# Avoid notification popup peek when app is in foreground

Tags: android

From https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior , I really we are able to notify user, without showing a notification peek.

I would like to show a flashing liked icon, in status bar, without pop up notification peek. (If you watch the first video under section From https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-behavior , you can see the flashing in status bar)

### Flashing icon in status bar

[image]

However, I'm not entirely sure how to achieve that. Whenever I notify user, there will be a notification popup peek.

### Notification popup peek

[image]

My code is as follow

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext(), org.yccheok.notification.Utils.createNotificationChannel())
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
    .setTicker(ticker)
    .setColorized(true)
    .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_material_light))
    .setContentText(contentText);

mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(getStockAlertSound()));

mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

// Need BIG view?
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
// Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(contentTitle);
inboxStyle.setSummaryText(summaryText);
for (SpannableString notificationMessage : notificationMessages) {
    inboxStyle.addLine(notificationMessage);
}
mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I was wondering, when my app is in foreground, how can I avoid notification popup peek, but only show a flashing icon in status bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
```